# Problems Updating Bacula (`GLIBC_2.8' not found (required by /usr/bin/dpkg))

Tags: lenny, bacula

I have a server with Debian Lenny and Bacula 2.2.8 installed. I decided to update the bacula.

I tried to follow several tutorials I found on the web but ended with this error "**GLIBC_2.11**' not found" after I execute a `apt-get -f install` to install dependencies.

Comment: This is the output when i execute apt-get check The following packages have unmet dependencies.
  binutils: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.7-6 is installed
  dpkg: PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.7-6 is installed
        PreDepends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not installed
        PreDepends: tar (>= 1.23) but 1.19-1 is installed
  libc-dev-bin: Depends: libc6 (> 2.11) but 2.7-6 is installed
  libc6-dev: Depends: libc6 (= 2.11.3-4) but 2.7-6 is installed
  locales: Depends: glibc-2.11-1 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: And this is what i get when tryig to run apt-get -f install usr/bin/dpkg: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /usr/bin/dpkg)
/usr/bin/dpkg: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.8' not found (required by /usr/bin/dpkg)